# c# with matlab dll should be running on pc without matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment

i have a very big problem.

ich wrote a programm which is using a matlab dll. i build some classes with the matlab .net builder. it runs on my pc :)

the problem is, i want to use ist on a pc without matlab. so i installed mcr, but it dont run :(

what are the steps i should do? the system variable path is right... where i have to put the dll files? so many questions, please help me

Comment: How far did you get with the product documentation ?  In my experience, which does not include the .NET builder, Matlab documentation is pretty good by modern standards and I'm surprised that it doesn't clarify this issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

- The Matlab-"Compiler" can build an installable package that includes enough of Matlab for your App to run.
- You could port the Matlab-Parts of your Code to Embedded Matlab and translate Matlab -> C with `emlc`, which is included in some Toolboxes like the Realtime Workshop. The resulting C-code is usable completely without Matlab.

Comment: i had build c# classes because i need the values from the matlab methods, because it is too difficult to copy the matlab methods in c#.
i added the dll as reference and it works, but not on the pc without the matlab, there i only installed mcr.

Answer (score 1):

Installing MCR on the target machine is the right first step.  How did you build the .NET dll?  Did you use [DEPLOYTOOL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/compiler/br5w5e9-16.html) or [MCC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html)?  Note that the links I gave are for MATLAB Compiler.  Make sure you use the documentation for the particular version of MATLAB Builder you use, in your case probably MATLAB Builder NE.  If you do it right, the output of DEPLOYTOOL or MCC will be an executable that installs your DLL and its dependencies on the target machine.  In MCC, look for the `-B 'dotnet:'` option that tells the Builder to make a .NET dll.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup matlab runtime on the other PC.

It's pretty smaller than matlab.

Answer (score 0):

1. Installed MCR (Note : if dll is 32 bit, then installed 32bit MCR if dll is 64 bit, then installed 64 bit MCR)
2. In C# code add following references:

   a. `MWarray`
   b. `micrsoftcsharp`
   c. created dll
3. Add following in code:

   ```
   using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
   using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
   using (dllname);
   ```
4. Declare class. For example:

   ```
   Class1 test1 = null;
   ```
5. Create instance of `class1` class. For example:

   ```
   test1 = new Class1();
   ```
6. Call dll function / Invoke method. For example:

   ```
    MWNumericArray c = test1.createFit4((MWNumericArray)x, (MWNumericArray)y).ToArray();
   ```